# Declaring a backbone model with defaults relative to other fields

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How can I get the following code to do default based on other model values?
This is roughly what I have

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        name:"",
        surname:"",
        fullTextString:""
    }
});
model = new Model({name"John", surname:"Doe", fullTextString:"John"+" "+"Doe"})
```

What I want is:

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        name:"",
        surname:"",
        fullTextString:name+" "+surname
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default values is only used when you do **not** set the values, so what you want is not possible.

I would use the following to get the functionality you want:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        firstName: "",
        lastName : ""
    },

    fullName: function() {
        return this.get("firstName") + " " + this.get("lastName");
    },

    get: function( attr ) {
        if ( typeof this[attr] === "function" ) {
            return this[attr]();
        }
        return Backbone.Model.prototype.get.call(this, attr);
    }
});
```

This way you can initialize your model this way:

```
model = new Model({firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"});
```

And use `model.get("fullName")` to get the name "John Doe".

Comment: What he wants is easily possible. See my answer for an example.

Comment: @JohnMunsch - your answer does match what he asked for but sQVe's answer shows what the scenario really calls for

Comment: @JohnMunsch Of course there are different solutions, your example does force you to have to update two places for the name to be correct tho. My solution does not give you that trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want one of the attributes to be a calculated value based upon both passed in values and, potentially, default values (for example, if they specify a {surname: "Munsch"} but provide no name), I think the easiest thing would be to add an initializer like so:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        name:"",
        surname:""
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.set({fullTextString: this.get("name") + " " + this.get("surname")});
    }
});

model = new Model({name:"John", surname:"Doe"});
model2 = new Model({surname:"Doe"});

console.log("model fullTextString: ", model.get("fullTextString"));
console.log("model2 fullTextString: ", model2.get("fullTextString"));
```

Comment: If one would change her or his first name the fullTextString would also have to be updated in this solution.

Comment: @sQVe True, but that may or may not be likely in this scenario. I can't say I've had to overload "get()" very often :)